# Lost the last object assigned using rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using **Rails_admin** to have CRUD functionality over my models. I have two models **Category** and **Project**. A `project` can have one `category` but one `category` can be in many `project`s. The problem is when I created two different `project`s with the same `category` the previous one lost the relation, only the last one created keep it. How can I do to create different `project`s with the same `category`.

My models are:

**Category**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :category

end
```

**Project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :project

  def category_id
    self.category.try :id
  end
  def category_id=(id)
    self.category = Category.find_by_id(id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationships you are really seeking of are:

- Project `belongs_to` Category
- Category `has_many` Projects

The `belongs_to` relationship you declared for Category in the model file says that each Category object can only bind to one Project object.

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one to find out more about the two relationships you will be using.